# Resources to simulate automatic storage and retrieval system using anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

Currently I am modelling a high bay shelf in anylogic(personal learning edition) using Material handling library and process modelling library. Using jibcrane or overhead crane I am unable to store or retrieve pallets in all the racks. The pallet rack has 4 levels. Is there any other resource I can use instead of jibcrane or overhead crane to pick and drop the pallets in or from the racks?

Comment: please document the exact problem you have and show what you already tried, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Hard to help otherwise

Answer (score 0):

you can actually store and retrieve pallets from racks using a crane using some tricks, even though it doesn't make sense in the real world

Nevertheless, in terms of resources, anything from a forklift to a person agents can retrieve and store in racks.. In the rackstore and rackpick properties you have a resource section that is quite easy to use.

If the problem is the 4 levels, there are forklifts that can lift pallets really high, and anylogic takes into consideration the level in order to calculate the storage time.

But anyways, your problem is not very clear.. do you want to actually use cranes to store? Or did I answer the question you had at least partially??

Comment: thank you. I actually wanted to use crane but forklift is also fine. But now i want to categorise the racks into types to store items. Example: In  1 column i want to store items of type 1 and when i store the item the rackcell color should change to red indicating its occupied and when i retrieve it should turn green. Can we do that in anylogic learning edition?

Comment: i dont think you can do that